# How do I get the bottom two images to come underneath the top two images in css?

Tags: html, css

```css
/* Tells HTML5 to find the font-type-face that my OS has and then use that for heading 1
  and also centers the first heading */  
                     
h1{
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
     text-align:center;        
}


/* Tells HTML5 to use any of the font-types for my first paragraph in HTML source file
   if one is not available. Also clears some white space 
   from the left margin of the paragraph and finally tells it to give that paragraph
   a size of 20 pixels. */

p{
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
            padding: 20px;
            font-size:20px;  
}

/* Tells the language to find the only div tag and position it 0 pixels from 
  the top, 1.56 pixels to the right, and 1.88 pixels from the bottom. */

div{
 padding: 0 25em 30em; 
        
}

label{
 float: left; 
 width: 11em; 
 text-align: right;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 

}
  input{
     margin-left: 1em; 
     margin-bottom:.5em; 
  }
  span{
     color: red; 
  }

legend{ 
         font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
          

} 

/* All of the TextWrap classes are just for positioning and floating the four 
same images around the form input information        */

.Wrap1{
             float:right;
             margin:40px;
             width:200px; 
             height:200px;
}
.Wrap2{
             float:left;
             margin:40px;
             width:200px; 
             height:200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cookie Order Form </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Form_Design.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Cookie Order Form</h1>
<p>This form is a cookie order form for customers that purchased cookies from
Daron's Cookies Company and the following below must be filled out in order for each
customer to receive a final message that tells them when their order will be ready.</p>

<!--The customer will be sent to the HTML page named "submit form.html" after they
  click the "Submit this Form" button. The code below does this. -->
<IMG class="Wrap1" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie">
<IMG class="Wrap2" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie2">


<div>
 <form id="cookie_form" name="cookie_form" action="submit form.html method="get">

<fieldset>
         <!-- Below sets the title of the form-->
    <legend>Customer Order Form Information:</legend> 


 <!-- Creates the first left label to specify what should be placed in the text box
    the the right of the label. The rest below does the same.-->
 
  <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName">
  <span id="firstname_error">*</span><br>

  <label for="orderNumber">Order Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="orderNumber" name="orderNumber">
  <span id="orderNumber_error">*</span><br>
  
  <label for="date_of_order">Date of Order:</label>
  <input type="text"  id="date_of_order" name="date_of_order">
  <span id="date_of_order_error">*</span><br>

  <label for="email_address">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address">
  <span id="email_address_error">*</span><br>

  <label>&nbsp;</label>
  
  <input type="button" id="form_submission" value="Submit this Form">
  </fieldset>

  </form>

</div>


</body>



</html>
```

How do I get the bottom two images (in the picture) to come underneath the top two images using css without it affecting the cookie order form? I have looked in w3schools but I can't find anything on there about my particular problem. I have tried to the margin-bottom and margin-right attributes, but I think I need to do something else. Can someone please give me a website or hint to what I should do about this problem? A website would help and a general explanation. I also have attached my problem in a picture below: 
[Here is picture of my problem for anyone's viewing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au9le.png)

Comment: We do not recommend or find some website for you. You can search yourself. We expect some code that you are having problems with, and some explanation about what you intend, and what you got.

Comment: Hi, can you paste you code, then it will be easy for us to look at your problems :). Thanks

Comment: P.S.F.Romesh I pasted my html and css files. Please don't worry I am not done with this project yet. I haven't created an html file for the submit button. Do you think you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you post your CSS and HTML here, at https://jsfiddle.net.

Well, probably what you can do is to wrap them inside a div with **position: absolute**. Then you can **position the images as relative**, so that it does not affect the form styling. You can adjust who is in the background and in the front by setting up the **z-index**.

Just some suggested solution, probably you really should define your intention clearly, by what do you mean by "underneath"? And really, pasting your code will be very much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Container of what the images are in > Position: Absolute

Images > Position: Relative, Z-index: (high enough to push the images to the front)

Comment: I use inspect in my browser a lot to experiment with html/css, give that a go :)

Comment: tttt what do mean it's high enough to push the images to the front.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I had to improvise as your code only had 2 images not 4.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cookie Order Form </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Form_Design.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cookie Order Form</h1>
<p>This form is a cookie order form for customers that purchased cookies from
Daron's Cookies Company and the following below must be filled out in order for each
customer to receive a final message that tells them when their order will be ready.</p>

<!--The customer will be sent to the HTML page named "submit form.html" after they
  click the "Submit this Form" button. The code below does this. -->
<IMG class="Wrap1" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie">
<IMG class="Wrap2" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie2">

<div>
 <form id="cookie_form" name="cookie_form" action="form.html" method="get">

<fieldset>
         <!-- Below sets the title of the form-->
    <legend>Customer Order Form Information:</legend> 


 <!-- Creates the first left label to specify what should be placed in the text box
    the the right of the label. The rest below does the same.-->

  <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName">
  <span id="firstname_error">*</span><br>

  <label for="orderNumber">Order Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="orderNumber" name="orderNumber">
  <span id="orderNumber_error">*</span><br>

  <label for="date_of_order">Date of Order:</label>
  <input type="text"  id="date_of_order" name="date_of_order">
  <span id="date_of_order_error">*</span><br>

  <label for="email_address">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address">
  <span id="email_address_error">*</span><br>

  <label>&nbsp;</label>

  <input type="button" id="form_submission" value="Submit this Form">
  </fieldset>

  </form>

</div>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>
<IMG class="Wrap1" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie">
<IMG class="Wrap2" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie2">
</body>
</html>
```

and css

```
    /* Tells HTML5 to find the font-type-face that my OS has and then use that for heading 1
  and also centers the first heading */  

h1{
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
      text-align:center;        
}


/* Tells HTML5 to use any of the font-types for my first paragraph in HTML source file
   if one is not available. Also clears some white space 
   from the left margin of the paragraph and finally tells it to give that paragraph
   a size of 20 pixels. */

p{
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
            padding: 20px;
            font-size:20px;  
}

/* Tells the language to find the only div tag and position it 0 pixels from 
  the top, 1.56 pixels to the right, and 1.88 pixels from the bottom. */


label{
  float: left; 
  width: 11em; 
  text-align: right;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 

}
  input{
      margin-left: 1em; 
      margin-bottom:.5em; 
  }
  span{
      color: red; 
  }

legend{ 
         font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 


} 

/* All of the TextWrap classes are just for positioning and floating the four 
same images around the form input information        */

.Wrap1{
             float:right;
             margin:40px;
             width:200px; 
             height:200px;
}
.Wrap2{
             float:left;
             margin:40px;
             width:200px; 
             height:200px;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

I removed the padding you had in the div css, and added a clearfix to clear floats with 2 images in the hmtl. Works for me :)

Comment: No worries Joe glad I could help. If this answer work for you, don't forget to click the tick to accept the answer. Which will help others find the answer easier